# Laravel Jquery doesn't work when npm run build

Tags: jquery, laravel, vite

I am using laravel 10.15.0
Everything works fine in developer mode.

```
npm run dev
```

When I try to run npm run build the site doesn't work.

I assume JQuery is not connected.
The following errors are in the browser console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
    at app-0a175ba5.js:22:57
    at app-0a175ba5.js:22:221
    at app-0a175ba5.js:1:23
    at app-0a175ba5.js:69:37056
```

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
    at (индекс):328:17
```

My app.js file looks like this

```
import '../vendors/plugins/jquery/jquery.js';

import './bootstrap';

import '../vendors/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.js'
import '../vendors/plugins/overlayScrollbars/js/jquery.overlayScrollbars.js';
import '../vendors/dist/js/adminlte.js';
import '../vendors/plugins/toastr/toastr.min.js';

import '../vendors/plugins/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
import '../vendors/dist/css/adminlte.css';
import '../vendors/plugins/overlayScrollbars/css/OverlayScrollbars.css';
import '../vendors/plugins/toastr/toastr.css';

import Alpine from 'alpinejs';


window.Alpine = Alpine;

Alpine.start();
```

What's my mistake?

Comment: did you setup new laravel 10 app or upgrade from laravel 9 ? becuse in laravel 10 use vite instead on webpack

Comment: But u did not import jquery - and $ undefined

Comment: @maksim Adding a string import '../vendors/plugins/jquery/jquery.js'; is not enough to import?

Comment: Look how alpine is imported.

Comment: @maksim If I remove import '../vendors/plugins/jquery/jquery.js'; and add 
import jQuery from 'jquery'
window.$ = jQuery;
stops working in development mode
Error: Uncaught jQuery not loaded!

Comment: Your jquery is not in your node_modules. Suggest to add that. The jquery in your `vendors` directory, did you copy that from somewhere? Maybe `import jQuery from '../vendors/plugins/jquery/jquery'`

Comment: @OlegAntonov i checked my old project - see gist. "laravel-mix": "^5.0.0". This code work 100%. https://gist.github.com/2618094/1e8da759e1a00d954abe958424001abb

Comment: @maksim please give a link to the working version in github again